# The effect of CSS,HTML,BOOTSTRAp gone when i upgrade my pc to windows 10 from windows 7

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Registration</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
     <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
  .form-control
{
width: 50px;
}
</style> 
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">


</script>
<body>
<div class="container">
 
 <div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading">
   <center><strong><h2>Register</h2></strong></center>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <form method="post" role="form">
   
    <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group col-xs-7">
      <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Fullname">

      </div>


     </div>


     <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
      <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Email address">

      </div>

      
     </div>

     <div class="form-group col-xs-7">
      <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Mobile number">

      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
      <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
       
       <input type="date" class="form-control" name="">

      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-xs-7">
      <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Address">
      </div>

     </div>


     <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
      <select class="form-control" style="width: 100px;" >
       <option>State</option>
       <option>Gujrat</option>
       <option>Maharashtra</option>
       <option>Goa</option>
       <option>Rajasthan</option>
      </select>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group col-xs-7">
      <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
       <input type="password" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Create password">
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
      
      <select class="form-control" style="width: 100px;" >
       <option>City</option>
       <option>Ahmedabad</option>
       <option>Mumbai</option>
       <option>Kolkata</option>
       <option>Delhi</option>
       <option>Banglore</option>
       <option>Chennai </option>
      </select>
                    </div>


     <div class="form-group col-xs-7">
      <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
       
       <input type="password" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Confirm password">

      </div>
     </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
      <strong>Gender</strong>
      <input type="radio" name="gender">Male
      <input type="radio" name="gender">Female

     </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group ">
     <center>
      <button class="btn"><span style="color: white;">Register</span></button>
        </center>
    </div>
   </form>
      </div>

    <div class="panel-footer">
     <center>by registerting you are agree to our <a href="#">Privacy policy</a></center><br>

     <center>Already have an account ? <a href="#">Log in</a></center>
    </div>
         </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

When i upgraded my pc from windows 7 to windows 10..the styles of css and bootstrap applied to the html page disappeared ..i installed the same browser and ran the program on it  and  used the same WAMP server which was earlier in windows 7....How can i overcome this problem....is there any solution to make my program look like how it was before in windows 7...........I added picture also please look at it

Comment: So from what i see you upgrade your pc and your bootstrap style sheet is deleted?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not possible actually, make sure you have css files present on root where your index file is.

Comment: yes i forgot to add that files..thank you now it is working

Comment: Sounds great :) Enjoy!!

Answer (score 1):

Ronak, you're not including the external stylesheets in this example (styles.css and bootstrap.css). Do you have those in the same folder in your local directory?

Comment: Yes i forgot to add that both file in my directory.now it is working..thank you